# Regex for a 5 digit number comma separated values e.g. 04700,04800,04900

Tags: java, regex, validation

Regex for a 5 digit number comma separated values e.g. 04700,04800,04900

I have to check comma separated values after every 5 digit number there should be a comma.

I have used several combinations of regex like

1. `String regex1= "\\d{5}";`  - check 5 digits
2. `String regex2= "^[0-9](,[0-9])*$";` - checks comma separated values
3. `String regex3= "^.*[,].*$";` - checks comma

But I need a combination of comma-separated values after every 5 digit number there should be a comma.

Please suggest a regex for this.

Comment: What is your current regex? Why does it not produce the correct result? What sample input makes your regex fail?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and show some effort please :)

Comment: i have used several combinations of regex like String regex1= "\\d{5}"; //check 5 digits
  String regex2= "^[0-9](,[0-9])*$"; //checks comma separated values
  String regex3= "^.*[,].*$"; //checks comma but i need a combination of comma separated values after every 5 digit number there should be a comma.

Comment: You tried everything you would need, just not all in one: `"^\\d{5}(,\\d{5})*$"` ought to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
public class FiveDigitPattern {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{5}(,[0-9]{5})*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("04700,04800,04900");
    boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
    if (matchFound) {
        System.out.println("Match found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is there any difference between ^\d{5}(,\d{5})*$ and ^[0-9]{5}(,[0-9]{5})*$ ..i think both expression gives same result.

Comment: there is no difference :)